# Laravel clicking on link adds to url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Okay I have a small problem.

When user clicks on a link it goes to website/create/business which is fine however if nothing is done but the link is clicked again, it goes to website/create/business/create/business for whatever reason.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="profile/{{Auth::user()->id}}">Profile</a>
            <a href="create/business/">Add Business</a>
            <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                Logout
            </a>
            <form id="logout-form" <a href="{{ url('home') }}" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('profile/{user_id}', 'ProfileController@checkid');
Route::post('update', 'ProfileController@updateProfile');
Route::get('create/business', 'BusinessController@addBusiness');
Route::post('create', 'BusinessController@createBusiness');
```

ProfileController:

```
public function checkid($user_id) {
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        return view('profile', [
            'id' => $user_id
        ]);
    }
}
function updateProfile(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    $twitter = $request->input('twitter');
    $facebook = $request->input('facebook');
    $instagram = $request->input('instagram');
    $telephone = $request->input('telephone');
    $user->twitter_personal = $twitter;
    $user->facebook_personal = $facebook;
    $user->instagram_personal = $instagram;
    $user->telephone = $telephone;
    $result = $user->save();
    if($result) {
        $message = 'success';
    }else{
        $message = 'error';
    }
   return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', $message);
}
```

BusinessController:

```
function addBusiness() {
    return view('addBusiness');
}

function createBusiness(Request $request) {
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $type = $request->input('type');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $business = new Business();
    $business->name = $name;
    $business->type = $type;
    $business->email = $email;
    $business->user_id = $user_id;
    $business->save();
    $address1 = $request->input('address1');
    $address2 = $request->input('address2');
    $town = $request->input('town');
    $city = $request->input('city');
    $postcode = $request->input('postcode');
    $telephone = $request->input('telephone');
    $address = new Address();
    $address->firstline_address = $address1;
    $address->secondline_address = $address2;
    $address->town = $town;
    $address->city = $city;
    $address->postcode = $postcode;
    $address->telephone = $telephone;
    $address->save();
    $result = $business->save();
    $result2 = $address->save();

    $business_id = $business->id;
    $address_id = $address->id;
    DB::table('business_address')->insert(array('business_id' =>  $business_id, 'address_id' => $address_id));
    DB::table('user_business')->insert(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'business_id' => $business_id));

    if($result && $result2) {
        $message = 'success';
    }else{
        $message = 'error';
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<a href="create/business/">` must be `<a href="/create/business/">` to solve this, because your current link is relative, not absolute, so when you click it again, the same reference is added at the end of your current URL.

Anyway, you should generate links in the Laravel way to avoid other issues in the future:

```
Route::get('create/business', 'BusinessController@addBusiness');

<a href="{{ url('create/business') }}">
```

or

```
Route::get('create/business', 'BusinessController@addBusiness')->name('createBusiness');

<a href="{{ route('createBusiness') }}">
```

Personally I prefer the second one, so if I change the route URL the links will still work, but it requires to add `name('yourRoute')` on your route definition.

Comment: how about this link?  <a href="{{ url('profile/{{Auth::user()->id}}') }}">

Comment: @Przemek You can't use moustaches inside moustaches, so it should be `<a href="{{ url('profile/' . Auth::user()->id) }}">`. I'm unsure right now, but i think you should pass the `id` as an array using a second parameter `<a href="{{ url('profile', [Auth::user()->id]) }}">` as in the [docs example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `route()` function. For this example: `<a href="{{ route('my_route_name') }}">Add Business</a>`. When your route changes it is automatically changed throughout the application.

You can name your routes like this:

```
Route::get('create/bussiness', [
    'as' => 'my_route_name',
    'uses' => 'BusinessController@createBusiness'
]);
```

Comment: You should also add a part about how to name a route to this, otherwise it isn't helpful.